# Disable hardware media key handling in MS Teams

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome, microsoft-edge, microsoft-teams

I have deactivated the setting in Chrome and Edge, but now it seems that it's visible also for MS Teams.
If possible I would like to disable it at the OS level. Also the volume bar on the left side. I don't need it at all. Can this be somehow disabled from registry or related?

[image]

Comment: why one? are there any limitations?

Comment: I guess I read it wrong, nevermind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the [How to get rid of the Volume OSD in Windows 8 / 8.1 and 10](http://wordpress.venturi.de/?p=1) post that has a solution for getting rid of the **Volume OSD** in Windows.

I downloaded [HideVolumeOS](http://wordpress.venturi.de/?smd_process_download=1&download_id=199), and it seems to worked perfectly. The correlated GitHub with source files and such is located here: [GitHub - HideVolumeOSD](https://github.com/UnlimitedStack/HideVolumeOSD)

> **The solution**
>
> During installation you can choose between 2 different versions.
> [image]
>
> **Tray icon version**
>
> The tray icon version of this app has a small context menu with 3
> items, which is pretty self explaining.
>
> To hide the volume OSD you can select the menu item "**Hide Volume
> OSD**" or just click on the tray Icon. With this item you can toggle
> between visible and hidden volume OSD. If you exit the application,
> the volume OSD is always restored to visible state.
>
> [image]
>
> During Installation the tool is added to the startup folder, therefore
> once hidden the toolbar remains hidden after a reboot.
>
> [image]
>
> **Silent mode version**
>
> This version was a user request from Daniel, who just wanted to hide
> the volume OSD without any system tray app. This one just hides the
> volume OSD at user login and quits then. In case you want to turn the
> volume OSD on again, just look into the program group called
> "**HideVolumeOSD**". There are 3 different launch icons:
>
> [image]
>
> [Source](http://wordpress.venturi.de/?p=1)